# How do I add lines to plot to highlight points using ggsurvplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Code is as follows:

```
Data <- read.csv(file='PFS.csv', header=TRUE)
fit <- survfit(Surv(Survival, Event) ~ 1, data = Data)

p = ggsurvplot(fit,
    # surv.median.line = "hv", # Add medians survival
    surv.scale = c("percent"),
    xlab="Months",
    ylab="Progression Free Survival",
    palette= 'black',
    # change the fonts for ticks
    font.tickslab=10,
    censor.shape="+",censor.size = 4, #default is 4.5
    # Change legends: title & labels
    legend.title = "Median PFS: 4.4 months; 95 % CI [3.3-5.4]",legend = c(0.7, 0.9),
    legend.labs = c("All Patients"),
    conf.int = F,
    xlim = c(0,40), #axes.offset = FALSE,
    break.time.by = 6,
    # Add risk table
    risk.table = F,
    tables.height = 0.2,
    tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),
    fontsize = 3,
    legend.key.width=unit(0,"line"),
    axis.title.y=element_text(hjust=0.50, vjust=2,margin = margin(b = 20),face="plain", colour="black", size="14"),
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,.21,.25,.50,.75,1))
  )
p
```

**Output:**
[image: Output]
The desired output:
(I know there are few differences in the two images, but I have mainly focused on the dotted lines leading to the 12 months and 24-month points.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach demonstrating with the available lung dataset.

Create a data frame for your points of interest. In this case, `times` will have the time points of interest, and `probs` will contain the probabilities at those time points. Probabilities will be derived from the `fit` model.

Using `plot` from the `ggsurvplot` object, you can add `geom_segment`. One to draw the vertical lines, and one for the horizontal lines.

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)

my_times <- c(250, 500)

df <- data.frame(
  times = my_times,
  probs = summary(fit, my_times)$surv
)

p1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)

p1$plot +
  geom_segment(data = df,
               aes(x = times, y = 0, xend = times, yend = probs), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_segment(data = df,
               aes(x = 0, y = probs, xend = times, yend = probs), linetype = "dashed")
```

**Plot**

[image: ggsurvplot with geom_segment lines added]

Comment: the principle is the same as with my answer?

Comment: Hi, TarJae - I didn't see your answer, but yes, it is similar. I think you might want to derive the probabilities from the `fit` model instead of entering probabilities directly. The lines in your plot do not intersect with the survival curve. If you add that (feel free to copy from my answer) I won't mind deleting my answer and upvoting yours.

Comment: Ben it is very Ok. And I agree with you. Mine was just an example how to draw this lines into a Kaplan-Meier survival plot. The OP can adopt it with his data (and now with your code). There is often the need for such lines. I was surprised that there is no ready solution like for the median survival ` surv.median.line = "hv"`. I upvote yours!

Answer (score 3):

you could use `geom_segment`. Add this two lines to your plot. This is for 12 Months. For 24 month it is analogue.

```
p$plot + 
geom_segment(aes(x = 12, y = 0, xend = 12, yend = 21), linetype = "dashed") +  # vertical
geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 21, xend = 12, yend = 21), linetype = "dashed") # horiontal
```

Working example:

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

p <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)

p$plot + geom_segment(aes(x = 250, y = 0, xend = 250, yend = 0.25), linetype = "dashed")+ 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0.25, xend = 200, yend = 0.25), linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: It works. If p is your plot. Use `p$plot + geom_segment(aes(x = 12, y = 0, xend = 12, yend = 21), linetype = "dashed") +  # vertical
geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 21, xend = 12, yend = 21), linetype = "dashed") # horiontal`

Comment: you are correct I was adding it to p instead of p$plot. Thank you very much for your help